# Как добавить div на Яндекс Карты рядом с меткой?

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты

Я не особо знаком с JS, поэтому нужна помощь. Я хочу реализовать [такое](http://i.cubeupload.com/eOhuUm.png)

С помощью конструктора Chrome, я переместил этот `div` изображенный на скрине в виде облака внутрь тега `ymaps-point-overlay`. Как добавить этот `div` через код? Использую версию Яндекс Карт 1.0. Добавляю карту через html. Изображенное на скрине облако, это не балун, который используется в ЯК, а просто картинка добавленная в div.

html:

```
<div class="map">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=kVbhcu1s3Dkltv6kZpiPcnI8Iooz42jb&width=100%&height=500"></script>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ymaps-point-overlay").append("<div>address box</div>");
});
</script>
```

css:

```
.addressBox {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('../img/address.png') no-repeat;
    width: 338px;
    height: 227px;
    padding: 19px 0 0 23px;
    top: -205px;
    left: -350px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Собственно проблема, в том что я хочу добавить через jQuery или JS див, который будет содержаться  внутри дива, который имеет класс `ymaps-point-overlay`. Как это можно реализовать. Событие `$(document).ready` не срабатывает. Я читал в доке про событие onLoad, но так и не понял как его им воспользоваться.

Comment: отсюда читайте, http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/dg/concepts/load.xml#param_onload и испоьзуйте уже api  2.0!

Comment: Про этот метод я читал. Но мне нужна именна карта версии 1.0. Неужели никак при помощи JavaScript нельзя добавить див в разметку? Почему при добавлении через метод append ко всем другим элементам на странице добавление проходит без проблем. Мне просто нужно событие, после того как карта загрузиться вызвать коллбек, который добавит div в html-разметку карты.

Comment: попробуйте вызов добавление дива по времени так как у вас происходит добавление элемента в ещё н существующий код в виду подгрузки карты,  а то без api ни как не обойтись.

Comment: Большое спасибо. То что нужно.